# How do I implement ToString() for my Player object?

Tags: c#, tostring

I want my `Player.ToString()` method to get the name with the score
and print it out. But it doesn't want to print out total score on the person.

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Arrows> trow = new List<Arrows>();

    public Player(string name = "")
    {
        Name = name;
    }

   public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

```
class Arrows : Player
{
    private int arrowOne;
    private int arrowTwo;
    private int arrowThree;

    public Arrows(int arrowOne = 0, int arrowTwo = 0, int arrowThree = 0)
    {

        this.arrowOne = arrowOne;
        this.arrowTwo = arrowTwo;
        this.arrowThree = arrowThree;
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
         return  arrowOne + arrowTwo + arrowThree;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Din totala summa är {0}{1}", Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it's the `ToString` call inside your arrows class.  If that's the case you only added one value to the `string.Format` method inside your `ToString`

Comment: Please minimize the code you post here. I suggest creating a main method which creates a Player object and outputs player.ToString(). Does that work or not?

Comment: Darren: Yes ur right, sorry bad explention were the problem were. Yes its the arrow score thats the problem. and i have test to put the Arrows.like this: return string.Format("Din totala summa är {0}{1}", Name,Arrows);
Then i get an error typ used like a veriable.

Thomas: can you show me how you imply?

Comment: I have edited your question in an attempt to express what I think you meant to express, but using correct English. Please review as best you can and make sure I didn't change your intent (I realize that for a non-native speaker, it might be hard to be sure, but at least take a look).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply want to change your `ToString()` method to look like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Din totala summa är {0}{1}", Name, GetScore());
}
```

Now, that said, you probably have a number of other problems. It seems highly unlikely that the `Arrows` class should inherit the `Player` class. Inheritance implies an "is a" relationship. I.e. your code is saying that a group of arrows *is a* player. I suppose in some specific game that might be true, but it's a very unusual design and doesn't seem like one you really meant.

On the other hand, your `Player` class already has a list of `Arrows` objects (reinforcing my suspicion that your `Arrows` class shouldn't inherit `Player`…if it were true that `Arrows` *is a* `Player`, why would `Player` have a list of them?).

Unfortunately, there's not enough information to know what you really meant to do here. Possibly you should just change the `ToString()` method in the `Player` class instead, e.g. something like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Din totala summa är {0}{1}", Name, trow.Count);
}
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Din totala summa är {0}{1}", Name, trow.Sum(a => a.GetScore()));
}
```

But I can't really say for sure.